# Does the sequence converges as $n → ∞$; if it does, find the limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the sequence converges as $n → ∞$; if it does, find the limit.$$\dfrac{2^{3n-1}}{7^{n+2}}$$I am not familiar with sequences and series. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $2^{3n} = (2^3)^n = 8^n$

Comment: `I am not familiar with sequences and series` Then what kind of answer do you expect to a question about finding the limit of a sequence? Btw, sequences and series are related, but not the same thing. As to the question, it may help to note that $\dfrac{2^{3n-1}}{7^{n+2}}=\dfrac{2^{-1}}{7^2} \cdot \dfrac{2^{3n}}{7^{n}}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite simple.$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^{3n-1}}{7^{n+2}}\\=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}(2^3)^n}{49×7^n}\\=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{98}\dfrac{8^n}{7^n}\\=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{98}\bigg(\dfrac{8}{7}\bigg)^n\tag*{}$But, since $\bigg|\dfrac{8}{7}\bigg|>1$, this [sequence](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-2/infinite-sequences-and-series/basics-of-sequences-and-series/definitions) diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as
$$\dfrac{2^{3n-1}}{7^{n+2}} = \frac{(2^3)^n}{2\cdot 7^2\cdot 7^n} = \frac{1}{98} \left( \frac{8}{7} \right)^n$$
and you can see that it diverges.